# Soundcloud API Auth via Golang 401 Error

Tags: rest, go, soundcloud

I'm attempting to connect to the Soundcloud API and obtain a token in Golang, but I get a 401 errr saying, "error":"invalid_client".

I've verified client ID and secret.

My redirect URI exists and is:

```
http://localhost:8080/platform/soundcloudCallback.html
```

My code is as follows:

```
func main() {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("scope", "non-expiring")
    v.Set("client_id", auth.ClientID)
    v.Set("response_type", "code")
    v.Set("redirect_uri", auth.RedirectURI)

    c.AuthURL = AuthEndpoint + "?" + v.Encode()
    c.Values = v.Encode()

    res := c.Request("POST", url.Values{})
}



func (c *Client) Request(method string, params url.Values) []byte {
    params.Set("client_id", "*************")

    reqUrl := "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, reqUrl, strings.NewReader(c.Values))
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    resp, _ := c.client.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    return body
}
```

Is my body in the NewRequest incorrect or is something else causing the issue? It's very unclear how localhost works with the API.

The solution is ensuring you have all of the following:

```
v.Set("scope", "non-expiring")
v.Set("client_id", auth.ClientID)
v.Set("client_secret", "f5e416ddf95aed8d077fccccc0a07821")
v.Set("response_type", "code")
v.Set("redirect_uri", auth.RedirectURI)
v.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code")
```

For anyone stuck on this, I made a blog article at blog.rileedesign.com detailing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you got the authentication process right. At first, you need to set up an app on SoundCloud - you have done that, because you have a client secret and a client id.

Then you open the SoundCloud login page, enter your username and password, and then (if you're logged in successfully) you're redirected to the Redirect URI with the authorization code. That code is very important, because with that code you can obtain the access token.

If you put in

```
v.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code")
```

you also need to set the authorization code with:

```
v.Set("code", AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
```

After that you'll get a response from SoundCloud with the access token, refresh token and so on..

EDIT:

So, for example your Redirect URI looks like this

```
http://redirect.uri
```

then, when the user authenticated successfully, you'll get redirected to that URI including the authentication code. It will look like this:

```
http://redirect.uri/?code=AUTHENTICATION_CODE
```

Then you make a POST request to

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token
```

including your authentication code, client id and client secret. The response will include the access token, refresh token and so on.

Comment: Ok so I first bring the user to a https://soundcloud.com/connect page where they connect the app. Then what do I do?

Comment: Got it, thanks so much! I'll be making a blog article detailing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to set the client secret, not only your client id.

I also wanted a non-expiring access token, but somehow this is not working. So I'm refreshing my access token everytime it is expired.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now that part works. I added: v.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code") and v.Set("client_secret", "**********"). However, Now I'm getting an issue with the grant type, {"error":"invalid_grant"}.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check this.

Go implementation of Soundcloud Oauth2

https://github.com/vitorsvvv/go-soundcloud-oauth